# Нахождение подстроки в строке и вывод слов с подстрокой

Tags: python

С клавиатуры вводится строка, а затем - подстрока. В строке найти все слова, в которых содержится заданная подстрока, и вывести эти слова целиком. Если слова повторяются, вывести все повторения.

```
s = input()
ss = input()
sss = s.split()
for word in sss:
    if ss in word:
        print (word)
```

Вот код который с этим почти справляется. Например если есть строка "Everybody has a Body", а подстрока "body", то второе слово, которое с большой буквы (Body) не выводится. Как сделать так, чтобы подстрока не зависела от регистра?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте метод lower, он всю строку в нижний регистр переводит

```
text = input().lower().split()
sub_str = input().lower()

for word in text:
    if sub_str in word:
        print(word)
```

если хотите сохранить регистр изначального текста и слова, можно так:

```
text = input().split()
sub_str = input()

low_sub_str = sub_str.lower()
for word in text:
    if low_sub_str in word.lower():
        print(word)
```

Comment: а если я хочу сохранить регистр слов?

Comment: @krumlyakov, менять регистр на месте, т.е. в цикле

Comment: @krumlyakov дополнил

Comment: @Ildar тогда он почему то не выводит слово, которое просто содержит эту подстроку

Comment: @krumlyakov ок я думал только совпадения слов нужны, исправил